# Is there a proof that uses (co)ends solely to establish the derived adjoint correspondence of e.g. deformable functors?

Tags: category-theory, localization, adjoint-functors, derived-functors, model-categories

In Riehl's book "Categorical homotopy theory" (the pdf may be downloaded on https://emilyriehl.github.io/books/) Exercise 2.2.15 on page 21 is given as follows:

> Suppose  $F \dashv G$ is an adjunction between homotopical categories and
> suppose also that $F$ has a total left derived functor $\mathbf{L}F$, $G$ has a total right derived functor $\mathbf{R}G$, and both derived functors are absolute Kan extensions. Show that $\mathbf{L}F \dashv \mathbf{R}G$. That
> is, show the total derived functors form an adjunction between the homotopy categories,
> regardless of how these functors may have been constructed.

I know that the standard (formal proof) which does not make use of the precise construction of the total derived functors is the one from Georges Maltsiniotis (to be found in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611952). However, I wonder if there is also a different proof which makes use of the left and right Kan extension formulas expressed as co/ends. More specifically, let $F \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ and $G \colon \mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{C}$ with $\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}$ homotopical categories. Denote by $\mathcal{C}_\sim$ and $\mathcal{D}_\sim$ the localizations at the corresponding weak equivalences and write $\gamma_\mathcal{C} \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}_\sim$ and $\gamma_\mathcal{D} \colon \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{D}_\sim$ for the associated localization functors. Since the total left and right derived functors are assumed to be absolute Kan extensions we may express them by the formulas

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{LF} = \text{Ran}_{\gamma_\mathcal{C}}(\gamma_\mathcal{D}F) \cong \int\limits_{c \in \mathcal{C}} \mathcal{C}_\sim(-,\gamma_\mathcal{C}c) \pitchfork\gamma_\mathcal{D}Fc\;, \qquad \mathbf{R}G = \text{Lan}_{\gamma_\mathcal{D}}(\gamma_\mathcal{C} G) \cong \int\limits^{d \in \mathcal{D}} \mathcal{D}_\sim(\gamma_\mathcal{D}d,-) \otimes\gamma_\mathcal{C}Gd
\end{align*}
The intuition would be (at least mine) that these formulas alone should be enough to prove the adjoint correspondence. However, I have not been able thus far to manipulate the corresponding hom-sets so as to obtain isomorphisms
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{D}_\sim(\mathbf{L}F(\gamma_\mathcal{C}c'), \gamma_\mathcal{D}d') \cong \mathcal{C}_\sim(\gamma_\mathcal{C}c', \mathbf{R}U(\gamma_\mathcal{D}d')
\end{align*}

It seems like there should be something, but it continues eluding me. So to summarize, my question is this:

> Is there a proof that uses the (co)end formulas solely? Was this what Riehl intended with Exercise 2.2.15, or was she referring to the proof as given in the paper from Maltsiniotis? If there is no (known) proof that uses the (co)end machinery, I would like to know why such an approach fails, as it should encode all the relevant information of the given Kan extensions.

Comment: Pointwise Kan extensions are not necessarily absolute. So why do you expect to be able to use the (co)end formulas?

Comment: @ZhenLin The knowledge that the Kan extensions are absolute may be further used to deduce that any other functor $H$ preserves the respective (co)end formulas, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Indeed. _If_ you assume and use the absoluteness of the (co)end formula you should be able to obtain the conclusion. But then you may as well just use absoluteness of the Kan extension.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, however, I feel like manipulating formal integrals is most often more illuminating (or at least easier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you insist:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{D}_\sim \left( \mathbf{L} F \gamma c', \gamma d' \right) 
& \cong \mathcal{D}_\sim \left( \int_{c : \mathcal{C}} \mathcal{C}_\sim \left(\gamma c', \gamma c \right) \pitchfork \gamma F c , \gamma d' \right) \\
& \cong \int^{c : \mathcal{C}} \mathcal{C}_\sim \left(\gamma c', \gamma c \right) \times \mathcal{D}_\sim \left( \gamma F c, \gamma d' \right) \\
& \cong \int^{c : \mathcal{C}} \int^{d : \mathcal{D}} \mathcal{C}_\sim \left(\gamma c', \gamma c \right) \times \mathcal{D} (F c, d) \times \mathcal{D}_\sim \left( \gamma d, \gamma d' \right) \\
& \cong \int^{c : \mathcal{C}} \int^{d : \mathcal{D}} \mathcal{C}_\sim \left(\gamma c', \gamma c \right) \times \mathcal{C} (c, G d) \times \mathcal{D}_\sim \left( \gamma d, \gamma d' \right) \\
& \cong \int^{d : \mathcal{D}} \mathcal{C}_\sim \left( \gamma c', \gamma G d \right) \times \mathcal{D}_\sim \left( \gamma d, \gamma d' \right) \\
& \cong \mathcal{C}_\sim \left( \gamma c' , \int^{d : \mathcal{D}} \mathcal{D}_\sim \left( \gamma d, \gamma d' \right) \odot \gamma G d \right) \\
& \cong \mathcal{C}_\sim \left( \gamma c', \mathbf{R} G \gamma d' \right)
\end{align*}

But I have to say that the expressions $\int_{c : \mathcal{C}} \mathcal{C}_\sim \left( \gamma c', \gamma c \right) \pitchfork \gamma F c$ and $\int^{d : \mathcal{D}} \mathcal{D}_\sim \left( \gamma d, \gamma d' \right) \odot \gamma G d$ are nonsense if interpreted literally because $\mathcal{C}_\sim$ and $\mathcal{D}_\sim$ may not have the (co)powers appearing in the formulae.
It would be better to understand the entire expressions as abbreviations for certain weighted (co)limits of $\gamma F$ or $\gamma G$ that happen to exist.

Comment: This is amazing :) thank you! It also seems like you only use that the corresponding Kan extensions are pointwise, or am I mistaken?

Comment: I am using absoluteness to move the (co)end in and out of the homs.

Comment: Is absoluteness really necessary for that? After all, (co)ends are just (co)limits and are thus preserved appropriately by the involved hom-functors.

Comment: Read carefully. I am not using the usual preservation properties here.

Comment: Could you explain that further or give me a hint? I don't see how this is not just the usual preservation properties.

Comment: The usual preservation property is that hom sends (weighted) colimits in the first variable and (weighted) limits in the second variable to (weighted) limits. But here I have taken a weighted limit in the first variable and a weighted colimit in the second variable to weighted colimits, and this is justified by absoluteness.

Comment: Why doesn't this follow from the standard preservation property? A limit of a functor is just a colimit over the opposite functor, same for ends and coends. Maybe you know of some literature where this is discussed?

Comment: I advise you compute some simple examples. Almost anything you try will (not) work.